# Bios/Firmware/EFI upgrade changed network port config

Tags: boot, networking, server, uefi

I did a EFI/firmware update on an Intel server board and the next thing I see is that the networking just stopped working... Little deeper and I saw that the NIC port labels were changed from em1, em2 to eth0 and eth1! I mean "ip link ls" showed different names. Also, the Boot screen started showing Network ports for booting which is fine.  My question is what process or steps led to these changes, particularly the change of port labels... mind you I did nothing at the Ubuntu level that prompted this change of Network Interface port names. And nothing in the upgrade process prompted me to change the names or specify any.

I changed the required files to get everything working. My question is the WHY this happened rather than HOW to fix the problem.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: That is a question better asked to intel dev or in an intel forum ? On recent ubuntu, this should not have happened because of `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04. Should have mentioned it.  I do not think it is an Intel issue because nothing in the firmware can possibly touch some file on some disk when the OS is not even booted!

Answer (score 0):

So what else changed that would have messed up the udev rules?  PCI address somehow?  MAC?  Would an EFI update have actually touched the NICs? (Perhaps if the onboards are also Intel NICs and it was more than just an EFI update...) but that's really a stretch.

solsTiCe is right, the udev rule should have prevented that from happening.

Comment: This is the bios and firmware update package I used: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22890/Intel-Server-Board-S1200V3RPS-Firmware-Update-Package-for-EFI   A related question: Where in the boot process or how and when does the kernel assign labels to the NIC and what decides the prefix: em or eth?